# Custom payment integrate in custom payment module

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

How to integrate payment integration method in the sample custom payment module.
I have two files.
Html and javascript.

I want to add these files in a sample payment custom module or I just want to say that I have to integrate payment API in a sample payment module.

Any link or any suggestion code kindly help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom payment method and add your required files there.

Follow this reference [module](https://bitbucket.org/hitesh-srtpl/magento2/src/0501cf3cdf574019a938b1ccc504965d7e7a9c3e/app/code/Magento/SamplePaymentGateway/?at=master) to add the custom payment method

After adding the above module in your Magento app/code directory run below command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f