# How to add custom payment module development logs?

Tags: magento2, module, development, developer-mode

I am attempting to build a custom payment module but as far as I got I get the error message `sh: -t not found` when checking out a test order
I saw [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245502/custom-payment-integrate-in-custom-payment-module) but the link in the answer is broken, I cannot place comments and didn't feel appropriate to answer with a question so here I am.

If there are some pointers to how Magento module should be debugged in these cases, usually there get a big dump of a log it hard to see what I'm looking for

EDIT: taking the code from [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/315662/88201) the log file created but is empty, putting it after all operations of the of an particular variable is executed results in some output. It appears i need to figure out which variable to debug, as well as the point where i should put the code

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in a phtml or php file and it will log the dump of **$order->debug()** in **var/log/payment-method.log**

```
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter(new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/payment-method.log'));
$logger->debug(print_r($order->debug(),1));
```

Comment: ohw cool i guess i can put this in any of the php files involved in the payment module?

Comment: Yeah, you can use it in any php/phtml file, maybe you need to change $order->debug() for whatever var you need to debug

Comment: ah i see, i'll check where i can make use of this

Comment: i finally found where i get the actual error 500 i added the code inside the execute function aaaand the log is empty :x did i miss anything?

Comment: so if the log file is created, the logging code is reached, maybe the variable you are trying to log is empty? You should add your findings to your question so we can see more information

Comment: ah so i should put the code after the variable is created hmmm